# Java loop structure that iterates over strings and works with multiple variables

Tags: java, for-loop, multiple-value

Today I am working on refactoring one of my old java exercises.

It is as simple addition program that asks a user to input some numbers, then returns the sum of all of the numbers entered.

```
package methodparametertest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodParameterTest {

    public static double adds(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e,
            double f, double g) {

       double sum = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;

        return sum;

    }

    public static double getDoubleInput(String valueWanted) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String askFor = valueWanted;

        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer or decimal value"
                + "for your numnber of "+askFor);

        double valueGiven = input.nextDouble();

        return valueGiven;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       double a = getDoubleInput("passengers");
       double b = getDoubleInput("odometer_miles");
       double c = getDoubleInput("fuel_gallons");
       double d = getDoubleInput("miles_per_gallon");
       double e = getDoubleInput("seats");
       double f = getDoubleInput("wheels");
       double g = getDoubleInput("lights");


       System.out.println("Your total number of things: " +adds(a,b,c,d,e,f,g));

    }

}
```

In the past, most of my program's logic was in my main method. I have made it my goal today to have as few lines as
possible in main, and package as much logic as I can into separate methods.

I still have several lines in main that use my getDoubleInput method to set the values for the variables a through g (which will then be used as parameters for my "adds" method.

I would like to alter this block and use a loop. Perhaps something that would work like this:

```
#Shell-like pseudocode

For i in (a b c d e f g)
For j in ("passengers", "odometer miles", "fuel gallons", "miles_per_gallon", "seats", "wheels", "lights");

do

double $i = getDoubleInput($j);

done

//OUTPUT

//       double a = getDoubleInput("passengers");
//       double b = getDoubleInput("odometer miles");
//       double c = getDoubleInput("fuel gallons");
//       double d = getDoubleInput("miles_per_gallon");
//       double e = getDoubleInput("seats");
//       double f = getDoubleInput("wheels");
//       double g = getDoubleInput("lights");
```

However, I cannot find an example of how to implement this in java. Most of the loops that I have seen only iterate over numericalvalues, not a defined set of strings.

Does anyone know of a loop structure that could A: iterate over strings, and B: work with two variables ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have an `adds` method; just use plain old addition. Put the titles in a list and iterate that:

```
double sum = 0;
for (String title : Arrays.asList("passengers", "odometer miles", ...)) {
  sum += getDoubleInput(title);
}
System.out.println("Your total number of things: " + sum);
```

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] strArray = Arrasy.asList(new String[] {"passengers", "odometer miles", "fuel gallons", "miles_per_gallon", "seats", "wheels", "lights"});

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str: strArray) {
   list.add(getDoubleInput(str));
}

System.out.println("Your total number of things: " +adds(list));
```

And then modify adds to accept lists.

Comment: Also worked nicely. looks like using an array is the thing to do!